# Step by Step How to embed PowerBI-JavaScript API into project HTML CSS JS

Tags: powerbi-embedded

I want to know way that can embed PowerBI-JavaScript into HTML JS CSS project. 
I have watched in https://microsoft.github.io/PowerBI-JavaScript/demo/v2-demo/index.html# but it not enough to clearly know ! 
So anybody can help me ! Step by Step ! 
Thanks so much !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While you can also view and download the entire playground code in https://github.com/microsoft/PowerBI-JavaScript/tree/master/demo, you can also take a look at the sample projects available in https://github.com/microsoft/PowerBI-Developer-Samples